# Different values returned for php session variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have been having this problem for the last two days now. I have two files on my local host.
http://localhost/project/sign-in.php and
http://localhost/project/form-handle/index.php

When a user lands on sign-in page a session variable is created

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$token = strtoupper(uniqid());
$_SESSION['token-string'] = $token;
```

I then put the session value in a hidden field

```
<input type='hidden' name='token-string' value='<?php echo $token; ?>'>
```

So far, so good. However, when I send the form values to http://localhost/project/form-handle/index.php
and return the value of the token string session, its different from what is in the hidden field. I am using jquery ajax to send the request.
Here is how I check for it in the form-handle page:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['token-string'])){
    $token = $_SESSION['token-string'];
    echo $token;
}
?>
```

The value returned is totally different! Its important to know also that the wrong value returned is a string generated by the function

```
strtoupper(uniqid());
```

Am I doing something wrong here?
Here is the jQuery that submits the form

```
$('#service-login').click(function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var form = $('#Ads-Login');
  var data = form.serialize();
  var url = 'form-handle/index.php';
  var method = form.attr('method');
  $.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    },
    error: function () {

    }
  })
});
```

The html form is here

```
<form action="" method="post" id="Ads-Login">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="token-string" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
<input type="password" name="Password" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Password">
<a class="btn btn-white dark-grey-text font-bold ml-0" href="" id="service-login"><i class="fa fa-play mr-1"></i> Login</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where does the AJAX call submit the form to? Can you see the correct value submitted in your browser's _Network_ console?

Comment: Yepp, the value submitted is exactly what is in the form and it's submitting to the url I gave

Comment: Sorry, you haven't shown where the request is being sent. What URL is it sending to?

Comment: http://localhost/project/form-handle/index.php let me add the javascript please

Comment: Please describe what you're seeing vs what you expect to see. From this code, I would expect to see a JavaScript alert showing at least the current session token value. It should be the same value as can be found in the current page's `<input>`. You could verify it with `alert(response + ' : ' + $('input[name="token-string"]').val())`

Comment: And thus my problem, both values are not the same, and like i said before, they are both strings generated by the given function.

Comment: How are you verifying that? Have you tried changing the `alert` as suggested above? If there's literally anything else in `form-handle/index.php` (like an `include` or `require`) either add it to your question or remove it from your code so it exactly matches the code in your question.

Comment: Why are you doing `ob_start()`? With that we can't be sure if the `echo` statement in the code you have is actually being used in the output you see. Is there something else that could be producing output besides that line? And if your sign-in page is the only code setting `$_SESSION['token-string']` then that could mean that somehow you are visiting that page twice, either refreshing the page, including that code in another file, or an ajax request gets redirected to it, etc.

Comment: I just tried alerting both as advised, they are still different. There's no other code lines in the files as well.

Comment: This is why it helps to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this locally at all. There must be other code you're not showing us

Comment: @CliffRono is your page reloading on form submission?

Comment: @zain I tried your advice, get rid of the form tags and collect the values individually, it still returns a different value.